# Passing data from HTML5 to database

Tags: javascript, database, html

I want to create an apllication similar to http://www.cambridgebrainsciences.co.uk/play/rotation-task, but I want to use an HTML5 canvas to build this application, instead of Flash.

However, how can I save data like reaction time and id of button to a MySQL database? Is this possible, or should I use only JavaScript to create this "game"?

Comment: Go step by step. First try to implement one small component. You can have the data eg in JSON at client and make asynchronous request at server to save it in database. Study about NodeJS. It can be used for Applications that requires quick interactions between client and server

Answer (score 0):

You need to employ an application server such as php to be the middle man between the client and the database. Then you would just make ajax requests to pages served by php which would read and write the data to/from MySQL and kick it back to your app.